# using existing kafka topic with avro in ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb, confluent-platform

suppose i have a topic, lets say 'some_topic'. data in this topic is serialized with avro using schema registry.
schema subject name is the same as the name of the topic - 'some_topic', without '-value' postfix

what i want to do is to create a new topic, lets say 'some_topic_new', where data will be serialized with the same schema, but some fields will be 'nullified'

i'm trying to evaluate if this could be done using ksqldb and have two questions:

1. is it possible to create stream/table based on existing topic and using existing schema?
   maybe something like `create table some_topic (*) with (schema_subject=some_topic, ...)`.
   so fields for new table would be taken from existing schema automatically
2. could creating of new schema with '-value' postfix be avoided when creating new stream/table?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a stream in ksqlDB based on another you can have it inherit the schema. Note that it won't *share* the same schema though, but the definition will be the same.

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_stream 
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='some_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

CREATE STREAM my_stream_new 
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='some_topic_new', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
    SELECT * FROM my_stream;
```